# Is it appropriate to answer a question with a gif?

Tags: discussion, answers

It is a lot easier (for me,  in some situations) to create a gif showing how to implement a solution (instead of writing it up in a list, like: 1. do this, 2. do this, ... 14. do this).

*Consider the following answer (which is short, so not the best example):* *Is the gif on the bottom of this post appropriate as a replacement for the instructions*?

(I would imagine that Stack Exchange might not want such answers, as they are not searchable by both this website, and search engines like Google.)

---

Use this formula:

```
=AND(A2=20,OR(A1=20,A3=20))
```

1. Select all the cells that you want to have the rule
2. Click on New Rule under Conditional Formatting
3. Enter the formula in the formula box (see screenshot)

[image: Select rule type "Use a formula to determine which cells to format".]

---

[image: Animated GIF demonstrating steps 1 through 3 above in Excel.]

---

PS. I am surprised that I haven't been able to find a similar question, please let me know if there is a duplicate.

Comment: Having both a written answer and an image/gif seems like a better approach. If a user isn't able to see the image for whatever reason, they can still read what they need to do.

Comment: Yes. *Especially* in Blender Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A gif like you show might be a great **addition** to your answer, but no more than that.

There are several occasions in which people won't have any use in your answer when it contains only such a gif.

What if:

- A user is visually impaired?
- The image is no longer hosted at the link you provided?
- A person can't see the gif due to domain or bandwith restrictions?

In all those cases your answer is worthless. Hence writing out the steps is the **only** way in which your answer preserves its value over time.

Comment: Just as a supplement, occasionally my internet connection starts losing packets and some QoS seems to kick in that makes loading GIFs really slow. So, I can *see* them but I need to wait a lot longer. Images are also loaded slowly but an on the same page image will render fully before a GIF starts looping. This is not exactly the same as blocking the domain but it still makes visual media vastly unreliable.

Answer (score 13):

I think that videos (GIFs, etc) and pictures should only ever be used to supplement more critical content like:

- lists of steps
- code
- error messages

By including the items in the dot points as formatted text that content can be searched and also viewed/read easily on all devices.

Answer (score 9):

I've fairly routinely used gifs for answers and I tend to have a few personal preferences to when I do it.

The answer *should* make sense without the animated gif - folks are going to want to work through your answer *without* having to keep up with a gif.

Gifs tend to be big, so keeping them short is good.

One finds in many cases *multiple* screenshots are better than one gif, as once again its helpful for people to follow on.

Its good for when you want to show where a specific menu is on your system, *and* to show a change in state

In your specific example - I feel like screenshots of each stage would be more obvious/clear. Now if your values weren't already formatted, the gif might be more informative, since it shows what you did, and the change that caused.